# issue with "/" and "." characters in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have little problem when I try pass a variable  (which contain a path) to sed.
It work well if variable didn't contain "/" character.
simple code from script for example:

```
sed "$1/d" $conf
```

file $conf contain next lines

```
aaa 
/bbb  
.ccc
```

When I try put:

```
scriptName aaa
```

all work well. But if i put

```
scriptName /bbb
```

I got

> sed: can't find label for jump to `bb"/d

message. Also I try

```
scriptName \/bbb
scriptName //bbb
```

Last falls with

> sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown command: `/'

How work with sed is I take path from variable and it contain special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to work around the issue:

Escape the `/` in your pattern:

```
sed '/\/bbb/d' filename
```

Supply a different delimiter, but the delimiter would need to be escaped (not the `/` in the pattern):

```
sed '\#/bbb#d' filename
```

Comment: thanks/ Another delimiter is a good idea.
But I need "" instead of '' (because I use bash variable) Is it work well?

Comment: @StepanLoginov Yes, you can use `"` instead of `'` in the examples above.

Comment: I think that '.' will still be interpreted by sed